# Sending an invite email with an HTML form and a PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms

After a user adds 5 emails and their name to form below, and then hits the "send" button, I would like to send a message such as "Hello, your friend 'sendername' recommends that you use thissite.com.  Please visit the site."  I would also like to specify the from address that this email has on it.

What PHP script could do this?

Thanks in advance,

JOhn

```
<div class="email1">
<form method="post" action="friends.php">
email address of friend 1:<br>
<input name="email1" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 2:<br>
<input name="email2" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 3:<br>
<input name="email3" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 4:<br>
<input name="email4" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 5:<br>
<input name="email5" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
your name:<br>
<input name="sendername" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="Send" id="Send"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function of php.

The code would be something like this

```
$msg = "a message";
$subject = "a subject";
mail($_POST['email1'], $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
mail($_POST['email2'], $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
mail($_POST['email3'], $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
mail($_POST['email4'], $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
mail($_POST['email5'], $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
```

Also changing your form to that would make the code more easy

```
<div class="email1">
<form method="post" action="friends.php">
email address of friend 1:<br>
<input name="email[]" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 2:<br>
<input name="email[]" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 3:<br>
<input name="email[]" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 4:<br>
<input name="email[]" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
email address of friend 5:<br>
<input name="email[]" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
your name:<br>
<input name="sendername" type="text" size="55"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="Send" id="Send"/>
</form>
```

It would recude the code to

Hope this helps.

```
$msg = "a message";
$subject = "a subject";
foreach($_POST['email'] as $email){        
mail($email, $subject,$msg,'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\n\r" );
}
```

your comment code

```
$msg = "<html><body><h1><a href="thissite.com">thissite</a></h1><img src='http://youserver.com/img.jpg'></body></html>";
$subject = "a subject";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\r\n";
foreach($_POST['email'] as $email){
mail($email, $subject,$msg,$headers);
}
```

Comment: cool... I'll give it a try.  Quick question: how would I make thisite.com a hyperlink in the body of the email message?

Comment: Also, how could I add an image to the bottom of the email message I send out?

Comment: the most easiest way would be to make the mail being an html mail. 

you would put that image on your webserver and link it the email

Comment: @RageZ You could add hyperlink for thissite.com also. little change in your $msg, <a href='http://thissite.com'>thissite.com</a> instead of <h1>test</h1>

Comment: @RageZ the code you provide works great, but when i try to change $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\r\n";
 to $headers = 'From: fromr@example.com' . "\r\n";, the HTML and images don't work anymore.  Any idea why?

Comment: @john use the $header variable by concatenating for example, $headers .= 'From: fromr@example.com' . "\r\n";

Comment: voila changed the link ^^ don't why you asked that!

Answer (score 0):

Just get those POST variable and use the mail() function from PHP. It's not hard

More reference about mail(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$to      = $_POST['email1'];
$subject = 'your subject';
$message = 'Hello, your friend '.$_POST['sendername'].' recommends that you use thissite.com. Please visit the site.';
$headers = 'From: fromr@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Repeat this process the times you need.

Comment: Cool... quick question:  how would I make thissite.com a hyperlink in the body of the email message?

Comment: Also, how could I add an image to the bottom of the email message I send out?